# Struggling with changing values of a given matrix while using the iteration in Julia

Tags: iteration, julia

I need to calculate the difference between V and V_new after each forloop.

I was expecting the printed result something like `[1 1 ; 1 1] [2 2 ; 2 2] [2 2 ; 2 2] [3 3 ; 3 3]`

However, what I got is `[2 2 ; 2 2] [2 2 ; 2 2] [3 3 ; 3 3] [3 3 ; 3 3]`

So it seems like the issue is coming from `V = V_new`.

I was trying to replace V in the first place before the for-loop starts and change the value of V_new only through the forloop but not V.

But it looks like the value of V also changes through the for-loop.

What could be the solution in this case?

```
   dif = 1.0
    it = 0
    itmax = 2
    V = [1 1 ; 1 1]
    V_new = [1 1 ; 1 1]
    # Iteration
    while it < itmax
        it = it+1
        println(it)
        V = V_new 
        for i in 1:2
            for j in 1:2
                V_new[i,j] = 1 + V_new[i,j]
            end
        end
        dif = maximum(abs.(V-V_new))
        println(V)
        println(V_new)
    end
```

Comment: Can't you just do a println(V) before starting the while loop to print the initial value & then, limit itmax or the inner loops to stop printing if needed ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about the code. Actually, I need to calculate the maximum difference between V and V_new after the forloop.

Comment: I changed the `V = V_new` to `for (i_a,a) in enumerate(agrid)
            for (i_d,d) in enumerate(dgrid)
                for (i_z,z) in enumerate(zgrid)
                    V[i_a,i_d,i_z] = V_new[i_a,i_d,i_z]
                end
            end
        end` and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`V = V_new` reassigns the `V` variable to `V_new`'s array, so they end up referencing the *same* array (`V`'s previous array is discarded). However, you needed `V` and `V_new` to reference *different* arrays, so you can compare the values before and after.

As you figured out, the fix was to copy `V_new`'s array's values to `V`'s array. However, your for-loop has many lines of code to figure out the indices from the arrays' dimensions. `V` and `V_new` have the same shape, so they are compatible for broadcasting:

```
V .= V_new
```

This is equivalent to indexed assignment `V[i] = V_new[i]` for all indices `i`; this mutates `V` at each index, it does not reassign `V`. Broadcasting itself is a loop that figures out the indices from the dimensions, so you don't have to write code to do it.